# Can anyone please tell where I have made the mistake in my code?

Tags: python, function

**Question:** You are driving a little too fast, and a police officer stops you. Write a function to return one of 3 possible results: "No ticket", "Small ticket", or "Big Ticket". If your speed is 60 or less, the result is "No Ticket". If speed is between 61 and 80 inclusive, the result is "Small Ticket". If speed is 81 or more, the result is "Big Ticket". Unless it is your birthday (encoded as a boolean value in the parameters of the function) -- on your birthday, your speed can be 5 higher in all cases.

```
def caught_speeding(speed,is_birthday):
    status=''
    if is_birthday==False:
        if speed<=60:
            status= 'No Ticket'
        elif speed>=61 or speed<=80:
            status= 'Small Ticket'
        else:
            status= 'Big Ticket'
    else:
        if speed<=65:
            status= 'No Ticket'
        elif speed>=66 or speed<=85:
            status= 'Small Ticket'
        else:
            status= 'Big Ticket'
    return status
```

When I am running the code mentioned below I am getting "Small Ticket" instead of "Big Ticket".

```
caught_speeding(81,False)
```

Answer (score 3):

`speed>=61 or speed<=80`

If speed is 81, the first condition is True.

True or (anything), is True

---

You should use `and`, or simply `61 <= speed <= 80`

Comment: Click here to review Stackoverflow's policy on answering novices posting their CS101  homework: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @DunnaAvinash by requesting that this homework be done for you, rather than working to figure it out on your own, you have deprived yourself of the educational-event that the homework was designed to create.  The next homework question after this one will be even more confounding than the first.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Understood, however, if he posts homework assignment question 1.02 and 1.03 to Stackoverflow, then without fail those will be downvoted as well for the same reasons given and his reputation will add up to -30 (Shown on the profile rounded up to zero).  I don't make the rules, if you want to escalate, I can point you toward the blog post where the founders of the site debate this very question.

Answer (score 0):

Within the if statement, when compared the speeds it needs to be changed to 'and' instead of 'or'. As written your telling the program to output small ticket only if the speed is over 61 or under 80. Since 81 is greater it would meet that parameter. Once 'or' is changed to 'and', 81 would no longer meet the requirements of a small ticket.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't understand what's happening in your code, you should step through it one step at a time to see what happens. In this case, `speed >= 61 or speed <= 80` evaluates to `True`.

The cleanest way to write your function would be something like

```py
def caught_speeding(speed, is_birthday):
    adjusted_speed = speed - 5 if is_birthday else speed
    return "No Ticket" if adjusted_speed <= 60 else "Big Ticket" if adjusted_speed > 80 else "Small Ticket"
```

Answer (score 0):

def caught_Speeding (Speed, is_birthday):
if is birthday
speeding = speed -5
else:
Speeding = speed
if Speeding > 80:
return 'Big Ticket'
elif Speeding > 60:
retuen 'Small Ticket'
else:
return 'No Ticket'